# Setting variable widths of partial views

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to set one partial view's width to be the same as anothers?

I have two partial views in my application. This first is a file upload, the second is a data table (using DataTables - datatables.net).

When a file is uploaded a log is shown under the upload controls. When the log is shown I would like this view to expand to be the same width as the table underneath it (or rather for it to be as big as is required by it's content's, centred over the table and no wider than the table). But I'm having trouble getting it to work - I seem to have great difficulty getting html widths and heights correct!

```
Html.RenderPartial("UploadFileView", Model.Log);
Html.RenderPartial("TableView", Model.Table);
```

UploadFileView.cshtml:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-border fieldset-auto-width">
    <legend class="legend-border-fix">Upload file</legend>
    <div id="element1">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
    <div id="element2">
        <button class="imageButton" id="uploadButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div id="log">
        @{ if (Model != null)
            {
                // Render log in a <textarea>...</textarea>
            }
        }
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

TableView.cshtml:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width">
    <table id="thisTable" class="default-table stripe hover table-bordered">
        @* Headers *@
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @* Data *@
        <tbody>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <td>@row[col]</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset.fieldset-auto-width {
    display: inline-block; /* Make field sets as wide as their contents */
}

#element1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
} 
#element2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Before uploading we have:
[image: Before uploading]

After uploading the upload area remains the same width:
[image: After uploading]

Comment: You would need to increase the size of the log area, since it's the contents of the fieldset that determine its width.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks Chris, that did it. Now however, the ChooseFile button, file name and upload button are left aligned. How can I get these to stay centered. I've tried putting a div around element1 and element2 and setting style=align-items:center

Comment: "align-items" is not a valid CSS property. Try `text-align`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Excellent, that's done the trick. Thanks. If you want to put in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the width of the "Upload File" fieldset when the log appears, you would need to increase the size of the log area, since it's the contents of the fieldset that determine its width. To center the "Choose File" line, you can simply apply `text-align: center` to the parent element, assuming the items in this line are all either `inline` or `inline-block`.